# Error while creating a PDF using DOMPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, dompdf

I am using `DOMPDF version (0.6 beta)`.I am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function append_child() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\application\helpers\dompdf\include\frame_tree.cls.php on line 220
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
$this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
$quoteId = $this->uri->segment('4');
$filename ='ship-'.uniqid().'.pdf';
$data = pdf_create($html, '', false);

$html = file_get_contents(BASE_URL.'index.php/admin/quotes/createQuotePDF/'.$quoteId);
```

I am stuck with this error for the past 4 hours.
Couldn't get much from Google as well.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In your code snippet the declaration of variable `$html` is after the function call `pdf_create`. The declaration must be done befor function call otherwise the variable will remain undefined & causes error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what mistake I made. I was including too many styles which it could not handle.Then implemented with minimal inline styles and it worked like a charm